# How to create list of objects with number of repetitions from other list with underscore?

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I have followed method that creates array of random numbers based on count (See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1030/))

```
$scope.generateRandomData = function(min, max, count){
       var out = _(count).times(function(n){return _.random(min, max)});
       return out;
    }
```

Im new in `underscorejs` and I wonder if I can easily create from random list new list where each element represents `value` and `count` of repetitions.

For example if I have:

*Input*

```
[1,4,2,3,4,4,1,4]
```

*Expected Output*

```
[ 
  {value: 1, count: 2},
  {value: 2, count: 1},
  {value: 3, count: 1},
  {value: 4, count: 4}
]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 var randList = _(count).times(function(n){return _.random(min, max)});

 var out =  _.chain(randList).countBy().pairs().value();
```

See Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1033/)**</kbd>

> **countBy**:
>   Sorts a list into groups and returns a count for the number of objects
>   in each group.
>
> **pairs**:
>   Convert an object into a list of `[key, value]` pairs.

It should return list of objects where 1st value is `value`, 2nd one: `frequency`.

After that run:

```
 var out2 =  _.map(out, function(value){ 
      return {'value':value[0], 'count':value[1]};
  });
```

Input:

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "value": "0",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "value": "1",
    "count": 7
  },
  {
    "value": "2",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```